# Creating an updatable list of items with Asp.Net MVC and SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application and installed the SignalR package.

I've created two simple model classes (they are simple for now but will extend it later):
`Item` which contains just a string property:

`public string Name { get; set; }`

and a `ItemList` which contains a List of `Item` as a property:

`public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }`

I've created a new Razor View (Items.cshtml) for interacting with the `ItemList`, I've added some static text to it and connected it up to the navigation menu.

I've created a new SignalR hub called ItemHub which extends from Hub (but it doesn't have any methods on it yet).

All is well so far.

What I'd like to do is have my page so it can list the current ItemList but also Add and Remove items. But I'd like this to happen using SignalR (via sockets) so that changes are immediately visible on all the clients connected to the page, any client can also Add/Remove items.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a regular **controller** for adding/removing items in your list, through actions. Inside both action methods (for adding/removing), you make a call to the **SignalR Hub** after saving changes:

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        // add item and save changes
        // ...
        // then invoke the hub
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ItemHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Invoke("ItemsUpdated", itemsList);
    }
}
```

You should have a javascript connected to the same hub, so when `ItemsUpdated` is called, you just update the GUI:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var itemHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('ItemHub');
itemHubProxy.on('ItemsUpdated', function(items) {
    console.log(items);
    // update GUI
});
```

How you are going to update the GUI, there are different options:

- You may use ajax to make a GET call to a partial view, and replace the entire resulting HTML in the appropriate DOM element (where your partial view is rendered in the first place)
- You may just pass the items list with the signalr message (with the `Invoke` method like above), and manually recreate the menu
- You may just reload the entire page (I don't really recommend this, just saying you could do)

If you already have a partial view with a controller action, containing the logic to create the menu using **Razor**, the first option would be fine, since you would isolate the render logic there.

The second option has the better performance, though you would have the render logic in the menu partial view, and in your javascript using signalr.

The third option is the simplest, but it's not recommended as you would re-render the entire page, consuming more bandwidth than necessary, taking more time, when you could just update the menu instead of the entire page (also other clients could have unsaved changes depending on what they were doing).